# Building an aside with fixed content

Tags: html, css, flexbox, css-position

```css
* {
  box-sizing:border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

section {
  width: 100%;  
  margin: auto;
  display: flex;
  background: gray;
}

aside,main {
  flex: 1 0 50%;
}

aside{
  flex: 0 0 50%;
  justify-content: center;
  background: #eee;

}

main {
  position: relative;
  color: white;
}


.container-text{
    position: fixed;
    margin-left: 12.5%;
    margin-right: 12.5%;
    margin-top: 24%;
    width: 25%;
}
```

```html
<section>
      <aside class="aside">
        <div class="container-text">
          <header class="hello">Hello</header>
          <div class="container-nav">
            <p class="how">How</p>
            <p class="are">are</p>
            <p class="you">you</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </aside>
      <main class="main">
          <div class="container-content">
          <h1>First heading</h1>
          <article>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse pharetra enim sagittis velit iaculis, a consectetur nisi sagittis. Etiam sagittis enim sapien, in ultricies nibh maximus quis. Nulla facilisi. Ut mattis gravida semper. Nam nec lacinia nulla. Proin euismod dolor lacus, id sagittis sem viverra accumsan. Curabitur eros est, vehicula vel nibh eget, gravida porttitor turpis. Vivamus a sollicitudin nisl.
          </article>
          <h1>Second heading</h1>
          <article>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse pharetra enim sagittis velit iaculis, a consectetur nisi sagittis. Etiam sagittis enim sapien, in ultricies nibh maximus quis. Nulla facilisi. Ut mattis gravida semper. Nam nec lacinia nulla. Proin euismod dolor lacus, id sagittis sem viverra accumsan. Curabitur eros est, vehicula vel nibh eget, gravida porttitor turpis. Vivamus a sollicitudin nisl.
          </article>
          <h1>Third heading</h1>
          <article>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse pharetra enim sagittis velit iaculis, a consectetur nisi sagittis. Etiam sagittis enim sapien, in ultricies nibh maximus quis. Nulla facilisi. Ut mattis gravida semper. Nam nec lacinia nulla. Proin euismod dolor lacus, id sagittis sem viverra accumsan. Curabitur eros est, vehicula vel nibh eget, gravida porttitor turpis. Vivamus a sollicitudin nisl.
          </article>
          <h1>Fourth heading</h1>
          <article>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse pharetra enim sagittis velit iaculis, a consectetur nisi sagittis. Etiam sagittis enim sapien, in ultricies nibh maximus quis. Nulla facilisi. Ut mattis gravida semper. Nam nec lacinia nulla. Proin euismod dolor lacus, id sagittis sem viverra accumsan. Curabitur eros est, vehicula vel nibh eget, gravida porttitor turpis. Vivamus a sollicitudin nisl.
          </article>
        </div>
        </main>
    </section>
```

I have a layout with an aside that takes up half the screen. The content inside the aside will stay fixed for a period of time. That's being stored in the container-text container. I would like everything in this container to stay fixed, however I would like the "hello" header text both horizontally and vertically centered. The "how" "are" "you" should be be at the bottom of the screen, centered with space between (they will be navigation). I managed to center a fixed container, but could not position the navigation. It is responsive left/right, but not top/bottom (I would like nav to stay at bottom and "Hello" to stay centered).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you are looking to achieve?

```css
* {
  box-sizing:border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

section {
  width: 100%;  
  margin: auto;
  display: flex;
  background: gray;
}

aside,main {
  flex: 1 0 50%;
}

aside{
  flex: 0 0 50%;
  justify-content: center;
  background: #eee;
  display:flex;
  justify-content:center;
  align-items:stretch;

}

main {
  position: relative;
  color: white;
}


.container-text{
   position: fixed;
   height: 100vh;   
   display:flex;
}

.container-text-inner {
  height:50%;
  position:relative;
  top:50%;
  display:flex;
  flex-direction:column;
  justify-content:space-between;
  align-items:center;
}

.container-nav {
  display:flex;
  flex-wrap: no-wrap;
  margin-bottom:15px;
}

.container-nav p {
margin-right:15px;
}
```

```html
<section>
      <aside class="aside">
        <div class="container-text">
          <div class="container-text-inner">
          <header class="hello">Hello</header>
          <div class="container-nav">
            <p class="how">How</p>
            <p class="are">are</p>
            <p class="you">you</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </aside>
      <main class="main">
          <div class="container-content">
          <h1>First heading</h1>
          <article>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse pharetra enim sagittis velit iaculis, a consectetur nisi sagittis. Etiam sagittis enim sapien, in ultricies nibh maximus quis. Nulla facilisi. Ut mattis gravida semper. Nam nec lacinia nulla. Proin euismod dolor lacus, id sagittis sem viverra accumsan. Curabitur eros est, vehicula vel nibh eget, gravida porttitor turpis. Vivamus a sollicitudin nisl.
          </article>
          <h1>Second heading</h1>
          <article>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse pharetra enim sagittis velit iaculis, a consectetur nisi sagittis. Etiam sagittis enim sapien, in ultricies nibh maximus quis. Nulla facilisi. Ut mattis gravida semper. Nam nec lacinia nulla. Proin euismod dolor lacus, id sagittis sem viverra accumsan. Curabitur eros est, vehicula vel nibh eget, gravida porttitor turpis. Vivamus a sollicitudin nisl.
          </article>
          <h1>Third heading</h1>
          <article>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse pharetra enim sagittis velit iaculis, a consectetur nisi sagittis. Etiam sagittis enim sapien, in ultricies nibh maximus quis. Nulla facilisi. Ut mattis gravida semper. Nam nec lacinia nulla. Proin euismod dolor lacus, id sagittis sem viverra accumsan. Curabitur eros est, vehicula vel nibh eget, gravida porttitor turpis. Vivamus a sollicitudin nisl.
          </article>
          <h1>Fourth heading</h1>
          <article>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse pharetra enim sagittis velit iaculis, a consectetur nisi sagittis. Etiam sagittis enim sapien, in ultricies nibh maximus quis. Nulla facilisi. Ut mattis gravida semper. Nam nec lacinia nulla. Proin euismod dolor lacus, id sagittis sem viverra accumsan. Curabitur eros est, vehicula vel nibh eget, gravida porttitor turpis. Vivamus a sollicitudin nisl.
          </article>
        </div>
        </main>
    </section>
```

Comment: Yes but the 3 nav links on the bottom should be in a row. With a small bottom margin and a left/right margin to separate them a bit.

Comment: @TravisMartin I have edited the answer, check now please

Comment: Yes, sorry about the delay. Tweaked a couple things and works perfect now. Thanks for the help!